# FlatList renderItem error, TypeError: undefined (evaluating 'item.id')

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList where I put some data in from my database.
In the render method, the state.data is correctly displayed when I console.log it. But in the renderItem method I try to print the item object but it doesn't display and then the error appears:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')

This error is located at:
in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:662)
in FlatList (at PlanView.js:49)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in TestLocalisation (at App.js:9)
in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in RCTView (at View.js:44)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

I tried to fill the flatlist data with some random static data and it works perfectly.

There is my code:

```
render() {
    console.log("render => " + JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={this.addTraining}
                title="ADD">
            </Button>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.sport}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.distance}</Text>
                    </View>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

And this is what is logged in the render function:

```
render => {
"_array":[
{"id":1,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":2,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":3,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":4,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":5,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":6,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":7,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":8,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":9,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":10,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":11,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":12,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":13,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30},
{"id":14,"name":"lol","sport":"running","time":120392,"distance":30}
],"length":14}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the function supplied to the `renderItem` prop. The function will be called once for each item of you array.

Your `renderItem` function destructures the object which it receives and tries to read the value for the key `item`. In the object it receives there is no key `item`, therefore `item` will be `undefined` and the access of `item.name` will fail.

To resolve the issue you must refactor the function supplied to `renderItem` to destrcuture that object correctly:

```
renderItem={({ name, sport, time, distance }) =>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{name}</Text>
                        <Text>{sport}</Text>
                        <Text>{time}</Text>
                        <Text>{distance}</Text>
                    </View>}
```

or not use destrcuturing at all:

```
renderItem={item =>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.sport}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.distance}</Text>
                    </View>}
```

**Note the difference regarding the curly brackets** between

```
const withDestrcuturingFn = ({ a, b, c }) => console.log(a)
```

and

```
const withoutDestrcuturingFn = (object_with_props_abc) => console.log(object_with_props_abc.a)
```

Comment: Why the heck this is not explained in the official doc? :-(

Comment: this is not correct, it doesn't matter destructed or not. OP mutates array and gets undefiend

Comment: This is incorrect! The render callback gets the following: 

`{ item: ItemT;  index: number; separators: {/* functions */} }`

So the OP is correctly destructuring to get access to `item`

Comment: If that was the case OP would not have gotten item is undefined ;)