# Unable to evaluate item.id in React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a list of exercises using React Native's FlatList component, and I'm currently unable to successfully edit the name of the exercise.  Everything runs smoothly upon the initial render.  However, when I try to edit the exercise, the subsequent re-render returns the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')`.  If I check my local database, the data is successfully edited, but rendering it to the screen is another issue.  If I were to dismiss the error display and reload the app, however, the expected changes have been made to the exercise.

I've seen previous posts/responses surrounding this issue, but from what I can tell, I've tried the suggested solutions to no avail.

Here is the component responsible for rendering the FlatList:

```
function Exercises({ fetchExercises }) {

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const exercises = useSelector(state => state.exercises) // **passed to data prop**

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchExercises())
}, [dispatch])

<FlatList 
  data={exercises}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return <ExerciseListItem item={item} />
  }}
/>
```

Below is the action I'm dispatching in the useEffect:

```
export const editExercise = (id, changes) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: EXERCISE_START })
  axios.put(<endpoint>, { name: changes })
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({ type: EDIT_EXERCISE_SUCCESS, payload: res.data })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: EDIT_EXERCISE_FAIL, payload: err })
    }
}
```

...and here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  exercises: [],
}

const exercisesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EDIT_EXERCISE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        exercises: state.exercises.map(exercise=> {
          exercise.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : exercise
        }
      }  
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, I'm able to successfully **add** a new exercise to the list.  Not sure if that would make a difference, but it's worth mentioning.  Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446720/flatlist-renderitem-error-typeerror-undefined-evaluating-item-id) is a similar question that someone asked about a year ago with what would appear to be the solution to my issue, but I'm still not getting the expected results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show full code! Usually new devs mutate state, then get undefined in re-render

Comment: Could you plz also add the data object which you are passing to the list and the code where you are doing some manipulation on data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're not returning anything in your `map` which is leading to this error.

```
exercises: state.exercises.map(exercise=> {
   return exercise.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : exercise
}
```